# How to Scroll two datawindows simultaniously at a time?

Tags: powerbuilder

I have two datawindows with same number of columns and it is Freeform. I have arranged columns one after another(vertically).
    **How to scroll two datawindows simultaneously at a time in Powerbuilder 10.5?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the ScrollToRow method on the second datawindow.  However, since you have arranged your columns in a long vertical row, it is unclear if this will work for you.

There is also a SetColumn method on datawindow controls but this does not 'scroll' to the column to make it visible.

Datawindow controls also have ScrollVertical and ScrollHorizontal events which you might use as well.

Look up these methods in PowerBuilder Help for additional information.

Answer (score 3):

Put this code in the dw_1 ScrollVertical event to sync the dw_2.

```
dw_2.Object.datawindow.verticalscrollposition = scrollpos
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a link between the data of the 2 datawindows (there must be one, otherwaise, I do not see your point), you might consider to create a single datawindow.
Instead of

```
select col1A, col2A,...colnA from tableA
select col1B, col2B,...colnB from tableB
```

You would have

```
select col1A, col1B, col2a, col2B,.... from tableA, tableB where ...
```

Some caveats:

- As indicated, you need a link between the 2 tables.
- Update might be trickier: you can only define in the datawindow
  painter one table to be updated.  Programmatically, it is possible to
  change that,    however.